# Core Data Migration Between Different Models?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, migration, restkit

Working with an xcode project with a bunch of issues and TONS of unused/buggy legacy code - we recently made the decision to start a new project fresh and build up from there. Everything is much better, but I'm running into a core data migration issue.

The vast majority of this model is the same, with a few tweaks - the model only includes 6 objects and there's only one object that I really care about getting what the user has saved so when we release this and they upgrade that data is there. I created the new model basically from scratch in the new project, so I'm guessing the app is trying to access a specific model based on an ID or something that doesn't match?

Does anyone have any idea as to a potential solution?

The app is crashing at the assertion below:

```
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:options error:&error];

NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);
```

The existing app is currently on its second version of the original ModelA, and the new app only has a single new fresh ModelA on the first version. I'm guessing that might have something to do with it?

Comment: The project needs to contain both the old model(s) and the new one in order for migration to work. It checks the bundle for existing versions and attempts to create a mapping model (assuming you're using lightweight migration). If you aren't using lightweight migration, you'll need a mapping model. Otherwise, it'll have no idea how to migrate your stuff.

Comment: Interesting - how could I handle two object files, like foo.h and foo.m, with the same name and potentially different attributes between models?

Comment: I should've been more clear: by older models, I meant the models within your .xcdatamodeld file. You'll have to add that file into your new project, and then add a new version of that data model in there.

Comment: ok great! What's the best way to do this? Can I just click and drag the .xcdatamodel from one project to the other within xcode?

Comment: Are you using RestKit in your new project?

Comment: Yes I am using RestKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing my own heavy-weight migration. I added the old data model into the new project and did a one-time migration of the legacy objects to the new objects, storing them in the new database.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment, but my response was too long...

A silly question first... and I write this having never used RestKit...

Question One - Is it worth checking through any required Build Settings for RestKit in your new project?

Question Two - Shouldn't you include a value for `fromSeedDatabaseAtPath` in the method?

Pending satisfactory response to Question One, try this...

1st; Close your new project in Xcode. Open a Finder window, and use Finder to copy the old .xcdatamodeld file from your old project into the new project directory/folder, and rename the file name if necessary.

2nd; Open Xcode, and in your new project, select the 'Add Files to Project...' option in the File menu, and follow the prompts to add the old .xcdatamodeld file into your project.

3rd; In your code, create an `NSString` to represent the path to the old `.xcdatamodeld` file, and include that in your line of code after `fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:` for the method `addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:withConfiguration:options:error:`.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure what you mean specifically with question one - RestKit is not new to the project so I don't think it's a build setting issue. I've been using restkit for about 6 months now with multiple versions of the object model without problems.

Comment: I get the same issue: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134140.)" UserInfo=0x15defec0 {reason=Can't find or automatically infer mapping model for migration,

Comment: Also, am I going to need to generate the object files from the old model, or does the app just need the old model itself?

Comment: @Mike it was a silly question... I haven't used RestKit before, so that was my attempt to be thorough and to maybe trigger a thought about a setting that may have been missing.

Comment: I have come across `Code=134140` before... I suspect in your case it will be "Can't find...". Yes you will need to provide Core Data with all the elements it requires to complete the process in app, which means both the old and new model files will need to be included in your new app's Build Phases under Compile Sources. For clarity, this includes the old model as a separate `.xcdatamodeld` file, referenced in the method as an `NSString` path against `fromSeedDatabaseAtPath`, and the new `.xcdatamodeld` file, referenced as an `NSString` path against `addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath`.

Comment: I appreciate all your help thus far. That all makes sense - the one question I still have is regarding the actual object files themselves from the data model. If the old data model had object 'foo', but I dont intend to use the foo object in the new model, do I need to generate the foo.h and .m files in the new project?

Comment: I expect the process to effectively have the same outcome as a lightweight migration, which I do every month or so when my data model changes. You will only require subclasses for the `NSManagedObject`s that are in use - these `NSManagedObject` subclasses provide the hooks that make it easy for you to access data model entities and their attributes/relationships in your code - and so you only need them for the current data model - therefore foo.h or foo.m are not required.

Comment: I feel I do this too often, but I keep recommending it because this book was very valuable in my ongoing education in Core Data - buy a copy from The Pragmatic Bookshelf – "Core Data, 2nd Edition, Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud" (Jan 2013) by Marcus S. Zarra.